# R shiny app width shrinks after I close the modal

Tags: css, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to stack overflow and asking my first question, not sure I am able to give proper context or not but due to some privacy concerns can't share a reproducible code for this but if you have any clue what causing this or how can be fixed in R shiny, please help me out.
So this is how my app looks when it starts covering the full width of the window and is working fine[app starting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMC6O.png)

I have added a modal that displays an editable table for the end-user and that table is used for further calculation. So the issue is whenever I close the modal by clicking on `Close` button then the width of the app shrinks every time I click it.[After few Iterations on closing the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A392D.png)
This is CSS tag I am using for that modal, I hope this is not creating an issue
`tags$head(tags$style("#var_lever .modal-dialog {width: fit-content !important;}"))`
Uploading the image as well. Can someone tell why this could be happening or how to fix that? Thanks in advance

Comment: White space can be seen on the most right of the second image between the window and app width

Comment: Hi could you please supply a minimal working example, where the problem is reproducable

Comment: I'm experiencing the same in a quite complex app. Trying to produce a repr ex but without success for now. Did you find a solution, @SumitKumar ?

Comment: Hey @jey1401, I tried but didn't get a solution on that hence  finally decided to go without modal and displayed that content in a bsCollapse.

Comment: Thanks @SumitKumar, I finally found a solution posted hereunder.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit dirty but adding this piece of css fixes it for me:

```
body {
    padding-right:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: glad you got the answer and thanx for sharing it!!